# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'openlayers' using TypeScript definition file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-3

In a Visual Studio 2017 React application using TypeScrpt there is a component (Map.tsx) that utilizes OpenLayers v4.6.5.

The package.json file loads both the @types/openlayers and the "ol" module.

```
{
  "name": "mhc-maps",
  "private": true,
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.6.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/openlayers": "^4.6.9",
    "@types/react": "^16.3.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.23",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.5",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.12",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "foundation-sites": "6.4.3",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "ol": "^4.6.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.2"
  }
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openlayers

http://openlayers.org/

Note, the TypeScript definition file is located in /node_modules/@types/openlayers while the OpenLayers module is in /node_modules/ol.

In Map.tsx there is an import for the OpenLayers type definition file.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';
```

Various sets of code uses TypeScript OpenLayers definitions, for example

let vectorSource: ol.source.Vector = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: fnVectorLoader,
  strategy: (extent, resolution) => {
    return [extent];
  }
});

and the intellisense referencing the type definitions works properly indicating the definition file is located.

However, when the app is run the following error is displayed upon initialization as React loads all the components.

```
./ClientApp/components/Map.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'openlayers' in 'C:\Users\cp\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Maps\Maps.Website\ClientApp\components'
 @ ./ClientApp/components/Map.tsx 13:0-33
 @ ./ClientApp/components/Layout.tsx
 @ ./ClientApp/routes.tsx
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
```

It seems the /node_modules folder is not being searched for the OpenLayers module, but rather the application components folder (\ClientApp\components).

What's strange is the React and jQuery both have similar type definition files and corresponding node modules, and load w/o any problems.

The only difference I see is the OpenLayers type definition folder is /OpenLayers while the module folder is /node_modules/ol. Also, there is no default export in the OpenLayers definition file.

Any thoughts on the cause of this problem appreciated!

Comment: [There appears to be a @types/ol package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ol), have you tried installing that instead?

Comment: I tried the @types/ol package but every class has to be defined individually in the import statement which is cumbersome. Also, "proj" is not defined and I need that for fromLonLat(). Therefore, I was looking for an alternative and the /openlayers package seems to be more complete and easier to use.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you solve this @ChrisP?

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: No,   run  npm install --save @types/ol does not help