# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'openlayers' in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, openlayers

I'm trying to use openlayers with typescript, But there is a problem.

openlayers is used in MapSection component, below is the MapSection code

```js
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import * as ol from 'openlayers';

const MapSection: React.FC = () => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {

    const map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        })],
      target: 'map-section',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [36, 38],
        zoom: 16,
      }),
      controls: [],
    });
    map.getKeys();
  }, [])

  return (
    <section className='map-section'>
    </section>
  )
}

export default MapSection;
```

If I run webpack devServer, it gives error message like this

`ERROR in ./src/components/MapSection.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'openlayers' in '/Users/donghokim/recruit/angelswing-frontend-test-0.3/src/components' @ ./src/components/MapSection.tsx 2:0-33 6:18-24 7:19-27 8:20-29 11:16-23 @ ./src/components/App.tsx @ ./src/index.tsx`

It is weird that component try to find openlayers library in current directory.

webpack and tsconfig files are written like this

```
//webpack.config.js
import path from "path";
import HTMLWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';
import webpack from "webpack";

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', 'json'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react",
              "@babel/preset-typescript"
            ]
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
      eslint: {
        files: "./src/**/*",
      },
    }),
  ]
}
export default config;
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["build/**/*"]
}
```

I just want to know where can I get a point to start finding problem.

/// added package.json setting

```
...

  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "^6.4.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.5",
    "@types/openlayers": "^4.6.17",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.24",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure if you have installed `openlayers` package?

Comment: the node package is called `ol` only

Comment: yeah, I'll add package.json dependencies

Comment: I think this question is already exits https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242763

Comment: this problem is solved! I got to know that there is another types package for openlayers in link where Kanti gives. If using @types /ol package instead of @types/openlayers webpack and typescript find package as I want. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

use `npm i --save-dev @types/ol`
and then include the dependencies like:

```
import {Point, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, Polygon, MultiPoint, LinearRing, LineString} from "ol/geom";
const reader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
const writer = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
const parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
parser.inject(
  Point,
  LineString,
  LinearRing,
  Polygon,
  MultiPoint,
  MultiLineString,
  MultiPolygon
);
```

Then you can close this question please ;)